# RSS pubDate always "01-Jan-01 12:00:00 AM"

Tags: c#, rss, windows-8.1

I try to get pubDate value from RSS feed 2.0 but it always = "01-Jan-01 12:00:00 AM"
here is the rss feed

```
 <item>
<title>title</title> 
<description>desc</description>
<link>http://somelink.com</link>
<pubDate>Thu, 31 Jul 2014 11:13:58</pubDate>
<guid></guid>
<enclosure"/>
</item>
```

and my class is

```
public class Item 
    {
        [XmlElement("title")]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("description")]
        public string Description { get ; set; }

        [XmlElement("pubdate")]
        public DateTime Pubdate { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("link")]
        public string Link { get; set; }
    }
```

All items is working fine except pubDate always "01-Jan-01 12:00:00 AM".
Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You are not telling the XMLParser about the format of the property.
Try

```
[XmlElement("pubdate", DataType = "date")]
```